# How to Capture Screenshot of entire Scrolling Webpage using C#

Tags: c#, runtime, screenshot

I'm creating a report app, so I render images saved as html in the DB on a web browser using c# and take a screen shot of it to put it in the report.

The problem is if the image is large it doesn't appear fully in screenshot, so I need a method to capture a screen shot for the whole content of the browser regardless of it's size and regardless of scrolling.

Comment: Show some effort. You don't expect someone to work for you, don't you?

Comment: No I don't :) but I'm doing my best sir and cant find a way